# get all unhidden rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Is there a way to get an array of all the rows in VBA and then copy them to a new sheet?

I assume that the correct property is rows(index).Hidden, but I am not sure how to use this.

Is there an easy way?
My problem is mainly that I can't Dim something As Rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the visible rows:

```
Sheets("yourSheet").Rows.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy
Sheets("secondSheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

but you actually can Dim something as Rows, because the Rows property returns a Range, so you just Dim your variable as a Range.

If you want to clear your clipboard afterwards use:

```
Application.CutCopyMode=False
```

Also note that it's inefficient to use copy and paste in Excel.
You should assign one range to another if you can.

Comment: It returns an "Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: @soandos, I tested it in both 2003 and 2010, so I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy your second line and set the first equal to a sheet, sorry

Comment: is there a way to pastespecial the values?